# Flutter Just Audio background Package

Tags: flutter

When play any song then close the app with background playing after that start the app then recent playing song activity show, this good but i wanna that when start the app then app reload, how's possible?

Answer (score 1):

Just audio dont work in background use this [just audio background](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio_background) or **[audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service)**  is too much advanced or [audio player](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) ;

dont forget to add background mode in Xcode : [image: background IOS]

Hope it work for you ; ***Good luck***

Comment: I am also saying about just audio background package not just audio, I wanna reload data when app restart but when i m  opening app after play song then recent activity show

Comment: if you work on ios , try to add Background Audio on xcode
if u could change the package i recommend audio_service

Comment: I am using android only.. suppose i open my music player app then play a song after that close the app and then open the app , i m showing recent activity and not reload

Comment: in slider progress  ?